# ssis xml configuration modifies package xml - am i crazy?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can SSIS XML configuration actually alter the contents of a package?

I created a set of packages connecting to my local machine, and ran it. 
Then i created XML configurations
then i modified dtsconfig XML , changing the DataSource in the ConnectionString and the ServerName as well to a second server.

i was getting login errors so i viewed the code of my packages. the connection managers in the packages now had the second server, not the localhost connection i had coded in the package. I am absolutely certain that i did not modify the connection managers in the package, only the configuration.

So my question is, can SSIS configurations change the package itself?

Answer (score 3):

If you specify a config file at design time, then run your package, the properties of your design-time objects will be updated (in your design-time package) to the values specified in your config.

If you then save your package, it will be saved with the updated property values.

Comment: I agree it's kind of non-intuitive. What's really inconsistent (to me) is that it doesn't apply the settings until you run the package in design-mode.  It seems to me that in that case it should remove the changes once it finishes.  The alternative would be to apply the changes as soon as you specify a config file, so it was obvious what's going on.  Still, SSIS has a host of these oddities - this is not the weirdest!

Comment: is it also true that the config file sometimes gets updated even when you have not explicitly taken an action to overwrite it, such as removing and re-adding it and using the overwrite option? i find this behavior totally confusing.

Comment: Geoff, could you please take a look at my latest post regarding the above? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535873/ssis-xml-configurations-configs-overwrite-packages-does-ssis-change-config-w